# Thread safe return of value get by another function call

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some problem, which I could simplify like that: This is my code of base class:

```
std::string MyBase::get(std::string path) {
  static std::string data;
  data.clear();
  get(path, data);
  return data;
}
```

Get() are defined in base class like that:

```
virtual int get(std::string path, std::string &data) = 0;
std::string get(std::string path);
```

Base class is an abstract class, which has implemented above function get(std::string path) and calls get(std::string path, std::string &data) from concrete class. Function get(std::string path, std::string &data) is pure virtual function of abstract class, which overridden in concrete class.
Now, this is clearly not threat safe solution. I want to write thread safe function get(std::string path), which will call get(path, data) and return correct data.

Comment: Why did you make `data` static?

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem, that shouldn't even exist. Make `data` a local variable, and no one gets hurt.

Comment: Making it `static` makes the function non-reentrant, so there must not be two calls at the same time to that function. It doesn't actually matter whether they are from different threads or recursion, though there's probably no recursion going on here. Still, it's a "don't do that when it hurts" problem, unless of course there's more to it that you haven't told us.

Comment: On a minor note you should pass the string argument by const reference

Comment: You're going to need some kind of lock, e.g. std::mutex.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the string local, e.g.

```
std::string MyBase::get(std::string path) {
    std::string data;
    get(path, data);
    return data;
}
```

or leave out the indirection and the other `get()` and make this one virtual:

```
struct MyBase {
    virtual std::string get(const std::string &path) = 0;
};
```